# An inverse of the function $e^x$

Tags: calculus, functions

How can I prove that the function $L(x)=\int_1^xdt/t$ which is definte on $(0,\infty)$ is an invers of $\exp(x)$. Should I work on $L(x)\circ e^x=e^x\circ L(x)=x$. I am stuck.... Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the main theorem of calculus (Newton-Leibniz), and that $(e^x)'=e^x$?

Comment: Use derivation on the composition.

Comment: @Berci: Can I always do as Meisam did when I wanna verify two functions are the inverse to each other? I know the second point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to prove that $L(e^{x}) = x$. Consider
$$
\frac{d}{dx} L(e^x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{e^x}\frac{1}{t}\; dt = \frac{1}{e^x}{e^x} = 1.
$$
(by use of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

So that means that $L(e^{x}) = x + c$ for some constant $c$. Now you "just" prove that $c = 0$ by evaluating $L(e^{0})$.

Comment: Thank you. I got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Find the derivative of $L(x)$ so we have $L'(x)=1/x,~x>0$. So the function $L$ is increasing and so it has an inverse function, $$x=L^{-1}(y)$$ and $dx/dy=x$ so $x=Ce^y$. Try to find $C$.

Comment: Thank you. I got my answer.

Comment: well put, like usual! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be the inverse of $\exp$. We have:
$$
e^{f(x)} = x
$$

Differentiate using the chain rule to get:
$$
f'(x) e^{f(x)} = 1 \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{e^{f(x)}} = \frac{1}{x}
$$

Now use the fundamental theorem of Calculus together with the fact that $f(1) = 0$ to show that $f = L$.

Comment: Your first line assumes the result.

Comment: Thank you. I got my answer. That was a nightmare.

Comment: @Jim No. I just assume that $\exp \circ L = L \circ \exp = I$ and $\exp' = \exp$.

Comment: @Jim I changed the function name to make my argument clearer.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Yes, that does clear it up!

Answer (score 2):

An informal magic but may be suggestive  enough:

Let $t:=e^x$, then $\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx}=t$, that is, $dt=t\cdot dx$, or, $\displaystyle\frac{dt}t=dx$, hence 
$$\int \frac{dt}t=\int dx=x .$$
Where $t=e^x$ means that $x(t)$ is its inverse.

Comment: Magic and formal to me. +1

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb hint$: $L(x)=\int_1^xdt/t=lnx$ then $e^xL(x)o=e^x(lnx) = e^{lnx}=x$ and $lnxo(e^x)=lne^x=x$

Comment: But that uses the fact that $ln(x)$ is the inverse, which is to be proven.

Comment: @Valtteri No, what's to be proven is that $L$ is an inverse. If we prove that $L=\log$, we're done.

Comment: @Valtteri: g is inverse of f iff  to f.g=g.f=I

Comment: @GitGud Well, I just assumed we had no idea what the inverse of $e^x$ is, thus we need to work in purely what we are given and definition of the inverse, thus saying that this integral is the same as $log$ would be a bit circular, in my reasoning.

Comment: @Valtteri Maybe you're right. But I don't think it's right to downvote Maisam because the asker wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @GitGud Of course not, I did no such thing.